# Polymer 2.x: Behavior mixins using class extension; error: Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymer, polymer-2.x, es6-class

I'm trying to implement behavior mixins using class extensions as described [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#mixins) and [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#mixins).

settings-list-text.html

```
<link rel="import" href="settings-item-switch.html">
...
<script>
  class SettingsListText extends SettingsItemSwitch(Polymer.Element) {
```

But I keep getting the following console error.

> settings-list-text.html:32 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor SettingsItemSwitch cannot be invoked without 'new' at settings-list-text.html:32

settings-item-switch.html

```
<script>
  class SettingsItemSwitch extends Polymer.Element {
```

How can I use Polymer 2.x to import my custom behavior mixins using class es6 extensions?

Comment: I am guessing you did try to google the error message and it's not the caching thing described here https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/polymer-2-class-constructor-polymerelement-cannot-be-invoked-without-new-3539b8681665 or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520535/class-constructor-polymerelement-cannot-be-invoked-without-new ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#mixins

Your mixin code should look something like this:

```
<script>
    /**
     * @mixinFunction
     * @polymer
     */
    MyMixin = (superclass) =>
        /**
       * @mixinClass
       * @polymer
       */
        class extends superclass {
            constructor() {
                super();
            }

            myFunc(myParam) {
                //do something
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
const { SettingsItemSwitch } = [your namespace].[mixins_dir];
class SettingsListText extends SettingsItemSwitch(Polymer.Element) {
  ...
}
```

Namespace can be `window.AppName` and `mixins_dir` is where your mixins are.